# Maven: change version <properties> in pom.xml

Tags: maven, properties, jenkins, pom.xml

It is a question not of the project version!!!!!

I have a Maven pom.xml. Build project and release project deploy with Jenkins.
Before creating release want set in Jenkins before_version-own=0.0.25 after_version-own=0.0.27-SNAPSHOT

But before and after build "release version" we need set my version in teg properties for example:
i have in pom.xml

```
<properties>
        <version-own>0.0.21-SNAPSHOT</version-own>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.test-release</groupId>
                <artifactId>features-test-release</artifactId>
                <version>${version-own}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

before release I need set like this

```
<properties>
        <version-own>0.0.25</version-own>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.test-release</groupId>
                <artifactId>features-test-release</artifactId>
                <version>${version-own}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

after release I need set like this

```
<properties>
        <version-own>0.0.27-SNAPSHOT</version-own>
</properties>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.test-release</groupId>
                <artifactId>features-test-release</artifactId>
                <version>${version-own}</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Why not using the release plugin to solve this. Build your project featrues-test-release via release plugin and the version of this will be automatically set. In the current project where you have your dependency on that just use the release plugin to set the version to the next release. Or use the versions-maven-plugin.

Comment: Simply I described release process, need set manual properties version before and after release, but using eclipse it it isn't convenient

Comment: Why do you need those properties. As i described via release plugin you don't need such properties.

Comment: Build new release project with new dependency versions. After build set selected dependencies to SNAPSHOT.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven: change version properties in pom.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483118/maven-change-version-properties-in-pom-xml)