# Permanently change a property variable in a Maven pom.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I need to change a property value in my pom.xml. I checked many approaches, but I think that they don't resolve my problem. E.g. I cannot use the [maven-versions-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-properties.html) because the property value is not a version string.

My pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <myProp>myValue</myProp>    
</properties>
```

I want change value of myProp permanently in the pom.xml via the command line. Overriding the property at runtime with `-D` is not enough for me.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven: change version properties in pom.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483118/maven-change-version-properties-in-pom-xml)

Comment: But, the release plugin don't change specific property.
I already this command, but was other situation.
Release plugin is very nice to change version of project.
Thanks

Comment: You are right, this question is not a duplicate. Note that you should edit your question and add details when you find out that people misunderstand your question. I already did that for this time.

Comment: Thank you very much orbelis,
I really have many difficulty to write here because I don't speak(write) english very well, then not get explain

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, there is also a [StackOverflow in Portuguese](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese)

Comment: I know, but in english there is more answers, and I want talk with people that speak (write) English, thank you for me help :)